# program .exe run on cygwin but give exception on debugging and running on visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, cygwin

I can run my program when I call it from cygwin.
but on visual stdio when I want to debug it, I get following exception:

```
Exception thrown at 0x610DDA44 (cygwin1.dll) in .exe: 0xC0000005: Access 
violation writing location 0x00000000.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

I added my cygwin1.dll path to my project environment but it didn't work.

I am trying to build and run canfestival from this link : https://canfestival.org/code
please help to solve this exception.

Comment: In C++ code, compiled for PC applications (Windows as well as Linux), it is usually not possible to write to 0x00000000 - that's a `nullptr`. If it runs in VS but not in cygwin than your code does something different when compiled in VS. Writing to `nullptr` in VS compiled code would fail with exact the same runtime error.

Comment: Either you try to debug the code - on cygwin with gdb (but I never tried it - it's probably by far not that convenient as the VS built-in visual debugger). Alternatively, you can try to isolate the error in a minimal sample code. May be, it's simply an unchecked return value of a system function call which accidentally fails on cygwin but not in VS. Have a look at [Eric Lippert: How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Once, you have such minimal sample and are still stuck, you can [edit] your question and add the sample as [mcve].

Comment: Actually I want to use visual stdio debugger @Scheff

Comment: It is possible that `visual stdio` does not fully handle cygwin programs. If it is a cygwin program try first with gdb.

Comment: I found out the  reason was deleting -mno-cygwin flag from makefile, I switch to using linux .

Answer (score 0):

As Scheff has said, using vs and cygwin in combination is not recommended. then I tried hard to make my library file in visual stdio, and it is debuggable without cygwin now. Also many people suggested using debugger for cygwin such as GDB if making library with visual studio was not possible.